# Laravel Eloquent Model Syntax error or access violation on groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-models

MySQL structure

```
id
key
display_name
value
details
group
created_at
updated_at
```

Laravel resource index

```
    public function index()
    {

        $settings = Setting::groupBy('group')->select('id','group as name')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
        
        return view('settings.general'), compact('settings'));
    }
```

When I run the code its how error :

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'demodb.settings.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `id`, `group` as `name` from `settings` group by `group` order by `id` asc)

Comment: also enable strict=>false in database.php mysql connection

Comment: that is a very bad idea as it allows bad queries to run

Comment: i don't want to enable strict mode

Answer (score 1):

Every column has to be in the GROUP By or have a aggregation function like in the example `MIN(id)`

```
public function index()
{

    $settings = Setting::groupBy('group')->select('MIN(d) AS id,group as name')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
    
    return view('settings.general'), compact('settings'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your group by 'group' you can have more than one id per group so it's a pb of logic, you cannot* have id in the select list.

*since your query cannot guess

2 solutions depending of what you want to do :

- retrieve id from the select
- add id to the group by